# Error while preprocessing input data for LayoutLMv2

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-datasets

Hello Stackoverflow Community,

I am working on implementing LayoutLMv2. I am facing an error: [image: error]
during preprocessing data with LayoutLMv2Processor.

I am getting this error "ValueError: Class label -100 less than -1".
You can check the notebook through this [link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Uf0YqxImO9PcDMGUusCdCRiVcChPWUK3?usp=sharing).

Looking forward for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Install datasets 2.2.2 version.

pip install datasets==2.2.2

Comment: wow! is that magic? have you face this error before?
Anyways, thank you!